# Limitations of redis.pipeline()

Tags: python, redis, atomic, race-condition

Say I use `Redis` to create and maintain a hash `h[ url ] = t`, where `t` is the timestamp of the latest visit of the page `url`. So given an input `( url, newT )`, I want to do the following:

1. check if `url` is a key of `h`
2. if not, set `h[ url ] = newT`
3. if it is, compare the old timestamp `h[ url ]` with `newT` , and update if `newT` is bigger

Also I want to use `multiprocessing`, so I need to do this **atomically**. After reading the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/), I thought I could use `pipeline` to do this:

> In addition, pipelines can also ensure the buffered commands are
>   executed atomically as a group. This happens by default.

But then it says:

> A common issue occurs when requiring atomic transactions but needing
>   to retrieve values in Redis prior for use within the transaction. For
>   instance, let's assume that the INCR command didn't exist and we need
>   to build an atomic version of INCR in Python.
>
> The completely naive implementation could GET the value, increment it
>   in Python, and SET the new value back. However, this is not atomic
>   because multiple clients could be doing this at the same time, each
>   getting the same value from GET.
>
> Enter the WATCH command. [...]

My understanding is that I cannot use `pipeline` if I want to read the value of `h[ url ]` prior to updating it. Is my understanding correct? Why isn't this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipeline allows you to send batch of commands at once.

If you need to get some values, evaluate in Python and do some more Redis commands, you will not fit within one batch.

Options are two:

- use WATCH command to check, if related key did not change since your last attempt
- use Lua scripting and do the calculation on server side.